# Is python an ok language for a typing test sort of application as far as performance is concerned

Tags: python, programming-languages

Want to write a typing test application (GUI, windows). Is simple terms. app shows text, user types text, user gets typing speed result. [Example of an online one](http://keyhero.com/typing-tests-wpm/)
Is python an ok language to use with such a project? Note that some people can type upto 200 word/minute . thats a lot of keys per second. Can python keep up? I ask this coz I have heard that python being interpreted in somewhat slower than C++

and I have always wanted to learn (go beyond the getting started tutorial) python, so if performance isn't an issue I would go with python.

If python isn't suitable, kindly suggest some other language. I am kind of ok in php and know a bit of C#. C I am not good at.

Thanks

Comment: I really don't understand where this question could possibly be coming from. This is 2011, not 1976.

Comment: how dare someone was born without knowing everything from birth.

Comment: Python would handle 2 million words per minute easy peasy

Comment: A couple of days ago I processed 50MB text / minute with python (while building a Solr index - on the same machine - along the way ;) - code wasn't tuned at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Allow me to state this rather *into the blue*: Python is well up to the task of handling 200 words / minute input. Plus it's a nice language for rapid prototyping.

Comment: :) very nice answer, I really did smile.

Answer (score 2):

In short, yes, python is an acceptable choice. The application you are creating does not appear to be doing anything incredibly intensive, and even if it was, that doesn't mean python would be a poor choice. It is used in tons of reliable apps with great performance.